# Does the character encoding ISO-8859-13 cover extinct Baltic languages?

Tags: character-encoding

I was wondering if the character encoding ISO-8859-13 covers extinct Baltic languages like Golyad', Semigallian, Selonian, Old Curonian, and the Western Baltic languages?

Comment: Does any writing exist for these languages?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @McDowell said, I'd recommend that you use UTF-8, just in case they have characters which ISO-8859-13 doesn't cover.